# I was thinking about creating copy constructor for `A` class but I'm not sure which approach to take

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, copy-constructor

I was thinking about creating copy constructor for `A` class but I'm not sure which approach to take.

```
class A {
  private:    
    int a;
    int b;

  public:     
    A() { a = 0; b = 0; }
    int gA() { return a; }
    int gB() { return b; }

};                  

class B {
  private:
    int *x;
    int *y;
  public:     
    B() { x = 0 y = 0; }
    int* X() { return x; }
    int* Y() { return y; }
};
```

Comment: You will need to give `Alpha` a constructor and a `operator=()` that each accept a `const Beta &` parameter.   Optionally, exactly one of those can be implemented using the other - not a big deal in simple classes like this.   Remember to handle the case of the `Beta` containing null pointers in a sane way.

Comment: Nitpicking: I, II, and III are not expressions.  They are statements.

Comment: Alpha(const Beta& beta) :a{*beta.getX()}, b{*beta.getY()} {} . Using const int the argument causes error message : The object has type qulifiers that are not compatibale with member function "Beta::getY()" and "Beta::getX()"

Comment: class B is going to cause you a lot of pain.  Don't use pointers unless you have to, and when you do have to, don't use raw pointers, as unless you really know what you're doing, you will immediately introduce a lot of problems with memory leaks and/or use-after-free errors.  Value-semantics (as in class A) and smart pointers avoid those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems:

1. There is no way of creating an `Alpha` object or a `Beta` object that is not all zero, so `Alpha a1 = aBetaObject;` cannot do anything useful.
2. The get methods are not `const`, so they can't be used in `const` contexts.  You should ensure const correctness by marking the get methods as `const`.

You need to fix these two problems first.

Then, to support `Alpha a1 = aBetaObject;` and `a2 = aBetaObject;`, you need to provide a constructor to allow `Alpha` to be initialized with `Beta`.

```
Alpha(const Beta& beta)
    :a{*beta.getX()}, b{*beta.getY()}
{
}
```

Note that this is undefined behavior when `beta.x` or `beta.y` is a null pointer.  You can make a check:

```
Alpha(const Beta& beta)
{
    if (beta.getX() && beta.getY()) {
        a = *beta.getX();
        b = *beta.getY();
    } else {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"blah blah blah"};
    }
}
```

Or you can make sure that `beta.x` and `beta.y` are never null, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Do I need to create operator=(const Beta& beta) ? and what should be in the constructor Alpha(const Beta& beta)
    :a{*beta.getX()}, b{*beta.getY()}
{
}

Comment: @Sunny No, you don't.  The constructor converts the Beta object to Alpha automatically before assigning.  As for the constructor: answer updated.

Comment: III.  a2 = aBetaObject; is an assignment statement. Will this statement work without = overloaded?

Comment: @Sunny Of course it will also work if you overload `operator=`.

Comment: After fixing some obvious typos (`cosnt`, `}`, `return *this?`) and removing the redundant self-assignment check (`*this` is an `Alpha`, never a `Beta`), yes, it is correct, though unnecessary.

Comment: Alpha(const Beta& beta)
    :a{*beta.getX()}, b{*beta.getY()} {} . Using const int the argument causes error message :  The object has type qulifiers that are not compatibale with member function "Beta::getY()" and "Beta::getX()"

Comment: small modification for beta class function:  int* getX() { return x; }
        int* getY() { return y; }

Comment: It was previously posted as int *getX() { return x; }
        int *getY() { return y; }

Comment: @Sunny As I have pointed out, "The get methods are not `const`, so they can't be used in `const` contexts."  You need to fix this problem.